# Custom User Agent for HttpClient?

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

can I set a custom User Agent for a `HttpClient`?

I need to view websites in their mobile form.

Comment: This should have been posted 4 days, 12 minutes and 12 seconds later to be historical.

Comment: @LéonPelletier why?

Comment: 12/12/12 at 12:12:12. #random.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Here you go

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent",
                                 "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; 
                                  WOW64; Trident/6.0)");
```

Comment: headers are case insensitive anyway

Comment: what does `AllowAutoRedirect ` have to do with the question?

Comment: @torvin probably nothing, was a copy paste from existing code.

Comment: You can get header name from static Class HeaderNames:
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(HeaderNames.UserAgent, UserAgent);

Answer (score 52):

```cs
var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd("MyAgent/1.0");
```

There is also a TryParseAdd if you want to catch bad attempts at adding it and Add if you want to create the ProductInfoHeaderValue with a name and version number yourself.

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "my-user-agent-name");
```