# 404 when calling a c# web api from another c# web forms application

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

I have created a simple web api and when I access this from IE the web api returns exactly what I expected. However, now I tried to access the same web api from a web forms application using httpclient. But now I get a 404 error. But the api seems to work, because I do receive results when using a browser. Any ideas what goes wrong?
This is the code:

```
 HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
 {
     UseDefaultCredentials = true
 };

 HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
 client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://server/appdir");
 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

 HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("/api/environment").Result;
```

Comment: if you debug, the request url is the same than your webapi url?

Comment: I'll leave this to the WCF experts to answer, but until they work their magic...have tried to run wireshark or something similar to see whats going on under the covers?

Comment: Oh and just in case its all on one box (connection to localhost), most packet sniffers don't work.  For monitoring local host, I've had luck with RawCap http://www.netresec.com/?page=RawCap, and this winsock based sniffer from nirsoft:  http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/socket_sniffer.html

Comment: maybe use `client.GetAsync("/appdir/api/environment/").Result;` ?

Comment: Fiddler would sniff local to local. - http://fiddler2.com/

Comment: Well, I do run the web api release on an iis 7 server. And the front end web forms app on my dev box. When I browse with either IE or Chrome from my dev box to http://server/appdir/api/environment everything works fine. So it seems iis 7 knows what to do how to route the controller. It's just when accessing it from a web form where things go wrong. I will check out fiddler and wireshark and check what I can see there. Man, this costs so much time. Any interest in the web.config file of the hosted web api? I can post that if that is for any help. Thanks so far.

Comment: Guys, this is too stupid to be true, but the Ilya Bursov receives the points! I changed the lines to client.GetAsync("/appdir/api/environment/").Result;  and removed the '/appdir' from the base url and now it works! The strange thing to me is that it is still the same and I think the application directory should belong to the base dir. Anyway, many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is the code that worked.

```
 HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
 {
     UseDefaultCredentials = true
 };

 HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);

 client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://eetmws10v");

 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

 HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("/aim2/api/environment").Result;
```

Answer (score 1):

Wow. I was experiencing this same error this weekend and I cannot imagine how flimsy the cause of the problem was.

This is what worked for me:

```
string _baseAddress = "http://localhost/webapi/";
string controllerURL = "api/School";

client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_baseAddress);
string result = client.GetStringAsync("controllerURL").Result.ToString();
```

The combinations of _baseAddress and controllerURL that caused the 404 error for me are as follows:

```
string _baseAddress = "http://localhost/webapi/";
string controllerURL = "/api/School";
```

or

```
string _baseAddress = "http://localhost/webapi";
string controllerURL = "api/School";
```

or

```
string _baseAddress = "http://localhost/webapi";
string controllerURL = "/api/School";
```

I sincerely hope something is done soon to remove this needless rigidity that is likely to waste many a developer's useful man hours.

Answer (score 1):

I work on this problem 2 days,and what work for me is to add custom user agent,
like in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13772937/custom-user-agent-for-httpclient)

code

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0)");
```