# Where do I add my user-agent information and how?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, rest, user-agent

I am building a rest API in ASP.NET Core 6.0

I am using several API's for a mashup, in which one of them demands that I set a "meaningful" user-agent. Can someone explain where (in which class or something) in the project I put the HttpRequest.UserAgent property and how exactly. I've been trying to search for a good explanation but it doesn't make sense to me.

the api I'm using is musicbrainz, in which i want the user-agent to look something like this:

`MyAwesomeTagger/1.2.0 ( me@example.com )`

Thank you for any help.

Comment: How are you trying to consume that 'musicbrainz' API?

Comment: I am using the API root URL to get the release-group of a specific mbId.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom User Agent for HttpClient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13772937/custom-user-agent-for-httpclient)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set a default User Agent on an HttpClient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44076962/how-do-i-set-a-default-user-agent-on-an-httpclient)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for a quick response in the comments - does this look right?

```
        {
              using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ApiMashupname/6.0", "emailaddress@hotmail.com");
                var response = await client.GetAsync(endpoint, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(data);
                return result;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Please put the new changes in the original Post using the Edit button.

Comment: I tried, but it didn't work. I know I seem incompetent.

Answer (score 0):

You should add user agent in UserAgent property of DefaultRequestHeader

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd("ApiMashupname/6.0(emailaddress@hotmail.com)");
```