# Reddit Ads API reporting endpoint returns 403 Forbidden despite access token

Tags: c#, reddit

I need to retrieve ads reports from [Reddit Ads API](https://ads-api.reddit.com/docs/). I can obtain an access token successfully, but can not get data from the reporting endpoint which returns a 403/Forbidden error message.

### 1. Authentication

First things first, I followed the [Authentication Quick Start Guide](https://ads-api.reddit.com/docs/#section/Authentication) by visiting the following URI :

```
https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/authorize?client_id=XXX&response_type=code&state=SSS&redirect_uri=https://test.company.com&duration=permanent&scope=adsread,adsconversions,history
```

*NB : [Documentation states](https://ads-api.reddit.com/docs/#section/Authentication:%7E:text=You%20may%20set%20this%20%22adsread%2Cadsconversions%2Chistory%22%20if%20you%20would%20like%20to%20your%20token%20to%20access%20everything%20in%20the%20ads%20API.) that specifying `scope=adsread,adsconversions,history` allows full read access from Ads API.*

Clicking the Allow button redirects to the following URL :

```
https://test.company.com?state=SSS&code=CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC#_
```

The code provided in the query string must be used for the following request.

### 2. Authorization

Then, a request is made to `https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token` using the following C# code :

```cs
private HttpClient httpClient;

public RedditService()
{
    httpClient = new HttpClient();
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Company/0.1 by Company");
}

public string RequestAuthorization(string appId, string appSecret, string code, string redirectUri)
{
    HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, new Uri("https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token"));

    string authValue = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{appId}:{appSecret}"));
    requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", authValue);

    requestMessage.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string> {
            { "grant_type", "client_credentials" },
            { "code", code },
            { "redirect_uri", redirectUri },
        });

    HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = SendRequest(requestMessage);

    return responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}
```

which successfully returns the following authorization data :

```
{
    "access_token": "TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "expires_in": 86400,
    "scope": "*"
}
```

*NB1 : Returned `scope` value is `*` which, I assume, means full read access, at least.*

*NB2 : No refresh token is provided because we have to set, in our case : `grant_type=client_credentials` and `duration=permanent`.*

### 3. Querying the API

After successfully obtaining an access token, I tried querying multiple Ads API endpoints but without success, especially the [Get Reports endpoint](https://ads-api.reddit.com/docs/#tag/Reporting/paths/%7E1api%7E1v2.0%7E1accounts%7E1%7Baccount_id%7D%7E1reports/get) that I'm interrested in :

```cs
public ReportData GetReport(
    string accountId,
    string accessToken,
    DateTime startDate,
    DateTime endDate,
    string[] groupByFields
)
{
    Uri requestUri = GetReportEndpointUri(accountId, startDate, endDate, groupByFields);
    HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, requestUri);
    requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", accessToken);

    HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = SendRequest(requestMessage);

    string jsonResponse = responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ReportData>(jsonResponse);
}

private Uri GetReportEndpointUri(
    string accountId,
    DateTime startDate,
    DateTime endDate,
    string[] groupByFields
)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> queryStringParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        { "starts_at", startDate.ToString("o", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) },
        { "ends_at", endDate.ToString("o", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) },
        { "group_by", String.Join(",", groupByFields) },
        { "time_zone_id", "GMT" },
    };
    string queryString = string.Empty;
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> queryParameter in queryStringParameters)
    {
        queryString += queryString.Length == 0 ? "?" : "&";
        queryString += $"{queryParameter.Key}={queryParameter.Value}";
    }

    return new Uri(String.Format("https://ads-api.reddit.com/api/v2.0/accounts/{0}/reports", accountId) + queryString);
}
```

I tried different URI values :

1. `https://ads-api.reddit.com/api/v2.0/accounts/{0}/reports` ([provided by docs here](https://ads-api.reddit.com/docs/#tag/Reporting:%7E:text=https%3A//ads%2Dapi.reddit.com/api/v2.0/accounts/%7Baccount_id%7D/reports)) returns `500 Internal Server Error`
2. `https://oauth.reddit.com/api/v2.0/accounts/{0}/reports` ([provided by docs there](https://github.com/reddit-archive/reddit/wiki/OAuth2#:%7E:text=Authorization%3A%20bearer%20TOKEN-,API%20requests%20with%20a%20bearer%20token%20should%20be%20made%20to%20https%3A//oauth.reddit.com%2C%20NOT%20www.reddit.com.,-Refreshing%20the%20token) and should be the correct URI) returns `400 Bad Request`
3. `https://www.reddit.com/api/v2.0/accounts/{0}/reports` (should not be used according to the doc) returns `403 Forbidden`

Finally, [the documentation states that a 403 error code means "Insufficient authentication scopes"](https://ads-api.reddit.com/docs/#tag/Reporting/paths/%7E1api%7E1v2.0%7E1accounts%7E1%7Baccount_id%7D%7E1reports/get:%7E:text=object%20Nullable-,403,Insufficient%20authentication%20scopes.,-GET) but I don't understand why as the scope value provided with the token was a wildcard (see above).

### Edit

I tried @davmos suggestion with user agent but C# `HttpHeaders.Add()` method and similar methods for setting `User-Agent` header won't work, throwing a `System.FormatException` with the message `The format of value 'android:com.example.redditconnector:v0.1.0 (by /u/myusername)' is invalid.`

I then tried to set user agent to something like `Company/v0.1.0`, but the response is `400 Bad Request` on `https://oauth.reddit.com` endpoint.

Using `httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("User-Agent", UserAgent)` succeeds to set user agent string as per Reddit documentation, but no success as well.

Comment: Your best shot looks like URI 2 to me. Perhaps the 400 is because your User-Agent is not in the format `<platform>:<app ID>:<version string> (by /u/<reddit username>)` as specified in the API rules [here](https://github.com/reddit-archive/reddit/wiki/API?ref=new.pythonforengineers.com#rules). Also, maybe the HttpClient is silently failing to set the User-Agent. There's a better way to set it via the `.UserAgent` property as detailed in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14211238/493680). Maybe you could use a tool like Fiddler to check all the HTTP data that's actually getting sent.

Comment: Thanks @davmos for helping.

I tried various variations of `android:com.example.redditconnector:v0.1.0 (by /u/myusername)` but without success.

`httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", ClientName);` throws a `System.FormatException` with the message `The format of value 'android:com.example.redditconnector:v0.1.0 (by /u/myusername)' is invalid.`

I then tried to set user agent to something like `Company/v0.1.0`, but the response is `400 Bad Request`.